# Python: Table where identical ID/Numbers with different values to being them on one line where the different values are appended to the right

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Table with some IDs that are identical on several lines but the assigned value is different. How is it possible to get a result where the ID is only shown once on one line and append the various values in multiple columns?

Starting point:

| ID | Column 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue |
| 1 | red |
| 2 | gray |
| 3 | yellow |
| 4 | orange |
| 1 | pink |
| 2 | white |

Desired solution:

| ID | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | red | pink |
| 2 | gray | white |  |
| 3 | yellow |  |  |
| 4 | orange |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe in a vectorized way:

```
>>> (df.assign(col=df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1))
       .set_index(['ID', 'col'])['Column 1']
       .unstack('col').add_prefix('Column ')
       .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None))

   ID Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
0   1     blue      red     pink
1   2     gray    white      NaN
2   3   yellow      NaN      NaN
3   4   orange      NaN      NaN
```

With `pivot_table`:

```
>>> (df.pivot_table(index='ID', values='Column 1', aggfunc='first', fill_value='',
                   columns='Column ' + df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
      .reset_index())

   ID Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
0   1     blue      red     pink
1   2     gray    white         
2   3   yellow                  
3   4   orange
```

Answer (score 0):

Groupby the ID and then compute the unique values

```
df.groupby("ID")["Column 1"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique())).unstack()
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. thanks a lot for the fast and tailored solution!

Comment: Apply pd.Series on each row is incredibly slow.